# 'Dispose' ambiguity error in C#

Tags: c#, dispose

I have the following code:

```
public partial class Painter : Form
    {
        private System.ComponentModel.Container Components = null;

        private const int m_intDIAMETER = 8;

        private const int m_intMOUSEUP_DIAMETER = 4;

        private Graphics m_objGraphic;

        private bool m_binShouldPaint = false;

        private bool m_binShouldErase = false;



        public Painter()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (components != null)
                {
                    components.Dispose();
                    //components = null;
                }
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.Run(new Painter());
        }


        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            m_objGraphic = CreateGraphics();

        }

        private void Painter_MouseDown(object sender,System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            //m_objGraphic.FillEllipse(new SolidBrush(Color.HotPink), e.X, e.Y, m_intDIAMETER, m_intDIAMETER);
            //m_binShouldPaint = true;

            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
            {
                m_binShouldPaint = true;
            }
            else if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {
                m_binShouldErase = true;
            }
        }
```

At the compile time my debugger generates the following error:

```
Error   1   Type 'Painter.Painter' already defines a member called 'Dispose' with the same parameter types
```

I think the Dispose method is generated by the program and that's why when I write it without generating the "Dispose" it gives me an error. But how can I fix it?

Comment: Your Form class already has a Dispose() method, stored in the designer file.  This looks like a cut-and-paste accident from .NET 1.x code, you do *not* want to use the Dispose() method you posted.  Just delete it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have another `Dispose` method in your designer generated file. i.e. `Painter.Designer.cs`, if you have some custom implementation in `Dispose`, then modify the one in `Painter.Designer.cs` file or move it to your code behind.

Visual studio generates a `designer.cs` file with every `Form`, that file contains code regarding controls used on the form and also has `Dispose` method implementation. Since your code behind has one, you are getting an error of having multiple `Dispose` method in a same class. (Both files have the same class through `partial` keyword)

[image]

Comment: How can I find designer.cs file? The only two files that I have are Form1.cs and Form1.cs[Design] which only shows my Painter form.

Comment: @muggleBlood, expand your Form, in solution explorer and you will see the designer file. I just added a screen shot showing that.

Comment: After I modified my Dispose method, my program compiled with no errors but it also did not generate what I intended it to do. What I did to have my code work, is completely removed Dispose method from my Form1.cs file as well as private System.Windows.Forms.Container components = null;. After it my program compiled with no errors and generated the result